# How can I write a function in Python that rounds a number?

Tags: python

How can I write a function in Python that rounds a number, in the usual fashion.
Numbers less than .5 round down, and .5 and above rounds up.

```
3.4 -> 3

11.9 -> 12

5.5 -> 6
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the Python function [round()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#round).  If you want to do it yourself, add 0.5 and then truncate.

Comment: Also note that `round()` returns a `float`, so if an `int` is needed specifically, `int()` should be used to type caste.  Example: `int(round(3.4))`

Comment: @Trey: `int(3.4+0.5)` is how you round to integers.

Comment: @Jochen Ritzel: now show him how to round negative numbers to integers.

Answer (score 1):

```
def roundNumberAccordingly(number):
    digits = str(number)

    integer = 0
    remainder = 0
    seen_decimal = False
    for i in range(len(digits)):
        if digits[i] == '.':
            seen_decimal = True
            continue
        elif not seen_decimal:
            delta = int(digits[i]) * 10 ** (len(digits) - i - 1)
            integer += delta
        else:
            delta = int(digits[i]) * 10 ** (len(digits) - i - 1)
            remainder += delta
    integer /= 10 ** (len(str(remainder)) + 1)
    print integer
    print remainder

    first = str(remainder)[0]
    if first in ('0', '1', '2', '3', '4'):
        return integer
    else:
        return integer + 1
```

Just kidding ;)

Comment: +1 just because it's worth it for writing that much code for a joke.